# Can 'hotseat multiplayer' refer only to turn-based games?

Tags: multiplayer, terminology

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotseat_(multiplayer_mode)), "hotseat" is a multiplayer mode of only turn-based games. But can one use "hotseat" to describe a one-screen real-time multiplayer game?

E.g., a game session can occur on one screen and players share a keyboard. Like in classic beat-em-ups and fightings. Is this 'hotseat'? Or just 'same-device multiplayer'?

Answer (score 2):

It can only be used to describe games in which only one player is playing at a time.
The players take turns to play on the same device, so it is not really possible to apply this on real-time games.

The term 'hotseat' is a metaphor in which the seat is too hot for the player to sit for too much time, forcing him to leave the seat to avoid pain.

Although the meaning is completely different, the metaphor is similar to the [hot potato](https://www.idioms.online/hot-potato/) one.